# regarding javafx?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Friends i am trying to develope a desktop application it's requirement is

1.It should have 2 browse button after clicking on that file open box should appear like 
jfilechooser in swing

2 Then i have to select that file and require it's url for future use.

3.My application contains just 2 buttons and on clicking on that i want to call a function that compare that file(logic for that i already written)
4.I am using eclipse for that

so overall i can say my  application is simple so what should i use javafx or swing for gui?
if any other conveniant option is present please tell me.please give me option which are open source

Comment: You can consider [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) as well for reaching the masses with your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it using Swing.

If you want it to be on a variety of devices (desktops, mobile or browsers) then choose JavaFX.

Comment: so there is no advantage of javafx for desktop application??

Comment: there are lot of benefits of using JavaFX but for a simple application, you can do well with swing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443354/what-is-the-difference-between-java-desktop-application-and-javafx

Answer (score 1):

If u require rich look and feel in your application,use JavaFx.Otherwise Swing is also good.

Comment: Please comment on the question for trivial answers.